# How to pass an element object & set data attribute to it ? (HTML + Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below is the code which i am using right now,

1. - **ON click the "#image-link" i am trying to store its element
     object to "rowurl" variable.**
2. - **ON click the
     "a.ck.ck-button.ck-button-save" i am getting a value on "geturl"
     variable**

& trying to save it to "Image" data-link attribute.

```
var rowidstate;
var rowstategetHTML;
var rowurl;

$("img#image-link").click(function(){
            rowidstate = $(this).parents('section').data('rowid');
            rowstategetHTML = $(this).parents('section');
             rowurl = $(this);
       });

    $(".ck.ck-button.ck-button-save, a.ck.ck-button.ck-button-save").click(function(){
      var geturl = $('.ck.ck-link-form input[type=text]').val();
      console.log(rowurl);  // i m getting the image element here i.e((<img id="image-link" class="link-editor img-upload img-fluid rounded mb-4 mb-lg-0 img-responsive-container ck ck-content ck-editor__editable ck-rounded-corners ck-editor__editable_inline ck-focused" src="/builderimages/about-img.jpg" alt="content image" lang="en" dir="ltr" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, main" contenteditable="true" data-link="">))
      if(geturl && rowurl){
            rowurl.attr("data-link", geturl);
     } 
  });
```

**Data attr ("data-link" of image) is not setting.**
As its not working right now any thoughts how to make it work ?
Thanks

Comment: Hello @msg can you please add your solution as answer ?

Comment: why do you say it is not working?

Comment: Data attribute is not setting here -             rowurl.attr("data-link", geturl);

Comment: Works for me. Can you provide a runnable example?

Comment: It works for me as well.